# how to show a laoding bar with tkinter and tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tkinter

I am currently loading a csv file with the help of tensorflow. Everything works without problems. Now I would like to try to create a gui using this method. With the help of a gui, I would like to create a loading bar to reflect the flow of the tensor flow. I came across tkinter because it has a loading bar. Can I integrate this with Tensorflow? If Yes, How do I do that?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time

def load_tf():
    df = pd.read_csv('my_data.csv')
    X = pd.get_dummies(df.drop(['ID'], axis=1))
    y = df['ID']
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=32, activation='relu', input_dim=len(X_train.columns), return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid', return_sequences=True))
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics='accuracy')
    model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
    model.save('tfmodel')
```

With my current Tkinter implementation, I can only run the function `step()`. I would like to do something like that with tensorflow. So when I click on a button, the bar should load.

```
root = Tk()

def step():
    for x in range(5):
        load_bar['value'] +=20
        root.update_idletasks()
        time.sleep(1)

load_bar = ttk.Progressbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='determinate')
load_bar.pack()
button = Button(root, text="Start", command=step)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: From what I remember, there isn't a way to get the progress of `<keras.Sequential>.fit(...)`, unless you define a special callback. You will need to run the training in another thread so it doesn't block the main one. Also using `time.sleep` with `tkinter` can cause a lot of problems so use `.after` scripts instead.

Comment: @TheLizzard Thank you for your answer. Can you generally do nothing much with the process of `<keras.Sequential>.fit(...)` or is it only with the Progressbar? Because I just saw that you can display a console output with tkinter. Because I'm thinking about just outputting the console in tkinter instead of the progress.

Comment: Looking at the [official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential#fit), you can pass in a `keras.callbacks.ProgbarLogger` object for the `callbacks` argument when calling `<keras.Sequential>.fit(...)`. The problem is that I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any idea how to implement it, but thanks for your research. I'll take a look at it and try to work something out.